# The name 'ConfigureAuth' does not exist in the current contex

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, owin

I'm getting an error when I'm attempting to run my page says that,

> The name 'ConfigureAuth' does not exist in the current context

in my `Stratup` Class. I'm sure all `AspNet Identity` libraries are installed. What do I need to do next, to try to fix this?

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(project_name.Startup))]
namespace project_name
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  On Build, running in IIS, running in IIS Express, running in Cassini, running on linux via mod-mono....??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using default Visual Studio project template, the `ConfigureAuth` method could be found in partial class `Startup.Auth.cs`. So make sure you didn't break anything when modifying project structure.

This is an example of `ConfigureAuth` method:

```
// For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
    PublicClientId = "self";
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true
    };

    // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
}
```

Comment: for me it was namespace issue, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30074236/2218697), hope helps someone.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I did use the using statement for the namespace differences but to no success. The thing I don't understand is if the namespace for both of the partial Startup classes was created at the beginning with the use of a template than why the errors? It uses the name of the solution for the Startup.cs partial and the name of the project for the Startup.Auth.cs partial

Comment: Can you list what namespaces are being used here?  I cannot find the `ApplicationUserManager`, `OAuthServerOptions`, etc.

Answer (score 8):

I had similar issue, To fix the issue I removed .App_Start from namespace in Startup.Auth.cs file. After that I was able to see the reference.

Answer (score 3):

It is either:

```
    [assembly: **OwinStartup**(typeof(Project-Name.Startup))]
    namespace project-name
    {
        public partial class Startup
        {
            public void **Configuration**(IAppBuilder app)
                    {
```

OR

```
    [assembly: **OwinStartupAttribute**(typeof(Project-Name.Startup))]
    namespace project-name
    {
        public partial class Startup
        {
            public void **ConfigureAuth**(IAppBuilder app)
                    {
```

Either rename OwinStartupAttribute  to OwinStartup
OR  Configuration to ConfigureAuth

Answer (score 1):

Kindly I note that the two partial classes (**Startup.Auth.cs** and **Startup.cs**) should be in the same namespace which is the root of the project, just change the namespace of **Startup.Auth.cs** to the same namespace of the **Startup.cs**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you originally create the project that there are no spaces in the name.
e.g. my app was called "DevOps Test" which was giving me errors when I ran it. 
I recreated it as "DevopsTest" and no longer had these issues

Answer (score 0):

namespace PAYOnline.App_Start

delete App_Start only namespace PAYOnline => It's welldone