# the name configureauth does not exist

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, owin

i'm trying this tutorial 
http://httpjunkie.com/2013/311/adding-mvc-5-identity-to-an-existing-project/
but is shows me an error
Error   5   The name 'ConfigureAuth' does not exist in the current context
 this is my startup.cs class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(TicketSystem.Startup))]
namespace TicketSystem
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }



      }
    }
```

this is Startup.Auth.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using System.Web.Mvc;

using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;
namespace TicketSystem.App_Start
{
    public partial class Startup
    {

        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });
            // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
            //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
            // clientId: "",
            // clientSecret: "");

            //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
            // consumerKey: "",
            // consumerSecret: "");

            //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
            // appId: "",
            // appSecret: "");

            //app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have different namespaces in both files:  `namespace TicketSystem.App_Start` and `namespace TicketSystem`. Make sure they are the same. Or alternatively add using statement:  `using TicketSystem.App_Start` in your startup.cs class.
If you check the example you'll see that both files are using the same namespace (`namespace MVC5FullApp`)

Comment: I am having the same issue. I did use the using statement to no success. The thing I don't understand is if the namespace for both of the partial Startup classes was created at the beginning with the use of a template than why the errors? It uses the name of the solution for the Startup.cs partial and the name of the project for the Startup.Auth.cs partial